# HTML : Issue with nested textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor, textarea

My code is given below. The problem is with `<textarea>`.

My form have a textarea and if I put another `<textarea>` in ckeditor value (HTML) then this inner textarea will close the parent textarea. What is the solution for it?

Please see the snippet output for the result. The submit button is showing outer then the textarea because the inner textarea closing it.

```html
<textarea name="editor1">
<section class="physicians wow fadeIn" id="Enterprise" data-wow-duration="1s">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="section_title">
              <h3>Physicians</h3>
              </div>
            
            <img src="http://108.163.162.202:8080/psi/psiweb/assets/default/img/physicians.jpg" class="img-responsive">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <form class="score_form">
   
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="FirstName1">First Name <span>*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="FirstName1">
                  </div>
                </div>
              
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="NPI1">NPI # <em>(Please enter your NPI # to receive your FREE PSI report.)</em></label>
                    <textarea id="NPI1" class="form-control"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Submit</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is invalid. remove the JS and simplify it to see how the first `</textarea>` closes the opening one:

```html
   <textarea name="editor1" style='width:100%; height:4em'>
<label for="NPI1">NPI # <em>(Please enter your NPI # to receive your FREE PSI report.)</em></label>
<textarea id="NPI1" class="form-control"></textarea>
Rest of form
    </textarea>
```

Instead, you must escape the < and > in your content:

```html
       <textarea name="editor1" style='width:100%; height:6em'>
    &lt;label for="NPI1"&gt;NPI # &lt;em&gt;(Please enter your NPI # to receive your FREE PSI report.)&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/label&gt;
    &lt;textarea id="NPI1" class="form-control"&gt;&lt;/textarea&gt;
    Rest of form
        </textarea>
```